# How do i save login info and status in cefsharp webbrowser

Tags: visual-studio-2019, cefsharp

I'm making a cefsharp web browser in visual studio 2019 and im using .NET Framework 4.7.2 and every time I open my browser to use it, and i login to something like Gmail or Google, etc. and after I was done I closed it and when i go to open the browser once more and i go back to Gmail or google and I half to log in again. can someone help me, i looked up this problem befor and it said I needed to create a lifespanhandler and i needed to open cefsharp-master and add a exsisting object to visual studio and I did that and i just keep getting errors

Comment: Are you specifying a CachePath?  See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#need-to-knowlimitations You don't need a lifespan handler to persist cookies etc.

Comment: Thank you, i added some of the code to my project

Comment: i have a problem with the example project in this post. when i added the code from program.cs to my projects program.cs i dont get any errors but when i login to something and i close the browser and open it back up it makes me log back in

Comment: Does the problem reproduce with the minimum example?  See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: If you have a problem you actually need to provide an example that reproduces the problem. Just saying it doesn't work isn't a question I can answer.